# Is it possible to generate a public private key pair in Azure Vault

Tags: azure, spring-boot, public-key-encryption, azure-keyvault, private-key

I am trying to create a public private key pair. I read about the documentation in azure portal about the create key. But its still not clear to me, if it is possible to generate a public/private key pair.

Can some one please tell me if it is possible ? and guide how it can be integrated with any spring boot application.

Comment: @Heath could you provide your inputs

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Key Vault only can generate a key with the RSA type. It's not a public/private key pair. If you're searching for a way to generate a public/private key pair for the SSH, I suggest you use the [SSH key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/ssh-keys-portal) in Azure. It will generate a public/private key pair for you, the public key is stored in Azure and you need to download the private key.